# Colab: Uploads files present in a directory

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using colab from google and running a model based off GPU. Once files are created on /tmp/ folder, how to upload them so that i can download on my local machine.? I saw examples on how to download a file, but not a folder, again here i dont know what are the list of files and their names.

thanks
Sudheer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to download a file from Collaboratory is to use

```
from google.colab import files
files.download('name_of_file.sometype')
```

If you want to download a complete Folder. You need to convert it into a zip and then download as above.

```
from google.colab import files
# import deps

!apt-get install zip && zip -r folder.zip folder_location
# download zip and zip the folder

files.download('folder.zip')
# download the folder.zip
```